# How do I position an object a percentage of the way to the right without going over at 100% using css-only?

Tags: html, css

I am running a template and trying to avoid javascript for any styling. I have a number between 0 and 100 that I would like to use as a `left: __%` on an element. Problem is that 100% is not working as I would like.

Please take a look at:
https://jsfiddle.net/stevenr4/ardoq7e9/

Notice how left: 50% means the left side of the element is at the 50% mark rather than the element being in the middle, and how left: 100% puts the element outside of the box rather than at the far right. The number can be anything between 0 and 100, so using  `margin: 0 auto` or `right: 0` will not work in this case.

Is there a css-only solution where I can use a single number between 0 and 100 to position an element relative to the width of it's container?

Comment: for right positioning I'd recommend you to use `right: 0;`. for middle add `transform: translateX(-50%)`

Comment: So for each number of `left:` you should add the same with minus in `translateX` thus it will be in the right way placed

Comment: @Sergey that last comment worked perfectly. Make that an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each number of `left:` you should add the same with minus in `translateX` thus it will be in the right way placed

Answer (score 1):

If you want to position in the exactly middle place I would recommend you to `transform: translateX(-yourPercent%);` like the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8002jr3z/)

And don't use transform when you are positioning it without the `left`(when using `margin:0 auto` or `right:0`) attribute because it ll translate in a wrongly